# XPath to get the element with the highest ID

Tags: .net, xpath

XML Source:

```
<documents>
    <document>
        <id>3</id>
    </document>
    <document>
        <id>7</id>
    </document>
    <document>
        <id>1</id>
    </document>
</documents>
```

I need the **document-element with the highest value in its id-element** (so `<document><id>7</id></document>` in the example). I can't change the C# code, it is `XMLDocument.SelectSingleNode(...)`, I only can modify the XPath used.

Is there something like `documents/document[id=max(id)]` or like `order by id descending` to get it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
documents/document[not(../document/id > id)]/id
```

Comment: +1 For shortest and correct XPath 1.0 maximum expression, besides cuadratic complexity...

Comment: thanks, great solution, you should get bonus points for this one!

Answer (score 18):

Besides Nick Jones XPath 1.0 correct answer, in XPath 2.0:

```
/documents/document[id = max(../document/id)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `preceding` and `following` XPath axes to check whether there is no greater value:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<documents>"
    + "  <document><id>3</id></document>"
    + "  <document><id>7</id></document>"
    + "  <document><id>1</id></document>"
    + "</documents>");

var max = doc.SelectSingleNode(
    "/documents/document[not(id < preceding::document/id)
                         and not(id < following::document/id)]");
```

If there are several maximum id values in the document the above code will return the first one. If you want the last element with a maximum id you can use

```
var max = doc.SelectSingleNode(
    "/documents/document[not(id < preceding::document/id) 
                         and not(id <= following::document/id)]");
```

If you want to get a list with all elements having a maximum id you can use the `SelectNodes` method:

```
var maxList = doc.SelectNodes(
    "/documents/document[not(id < preceding::document/id) 
                         and not(id < following::document/id)]");
```

XSLT version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <root>
        <xsl:value-of 
             select="/documents/document/id[not(. &lt;= preceding::document/id) 
                     and not(. &lt;= following::document/id)]"/>
      </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Would this not just give you the first one it came accross that was higher than the one before and the one after it?

Answer (score 1):

Have a gander at this link. 
It uses a function math:max().

There is a link for source for that function and explains how it can be implemented

http://www.exslt.org/math/functions/max/index.html

Hope this helps you

Comment: And after implementing this you can do something like this: /documents/document/id[number(child::text()) < max(number(child::text()))]

Comment: As far as I see, it is supported by several XSLT processors, but not by .NET ... am I missing something?

Comment: @Restuts, I need the document node, shouldn't it be more like: /documents/document[number(id/child::text()) = math:max(number(id/child::text()))]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, neither XPath 1.0 or XPath 2.0 define a sort() function. However, most *implementations* have a sort. For example, `<xsl:sort>` is available in XSLT implementations, and DOM4J has a sort by XPath method. I'm sure there is something similar in C# but you would have to change the C# code a bit.