# SQL XML Parsing in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqlxml

I have SQL Server table which has XML column that has data like below. Multiple records will be there in the table.
Let us say table T1 and Column C1.

Our requirement is   we need to get the latest data (by max of datereported, datecreated, dateupdated XML node  for individual sections like AAA,BB,CC).

```
<XMLDoc>
    <AAA>
      <Name>Name_A</Name>
      <Value>Val_A</Value>
      <dateReported>1/1/2001</dateReported>
    </AAA>
    <AAA>
      <Name>Name_B</Name>
      <Value>Val_B</Value>
      <dateReported>1/1/2014</dateReported>
    </AAA>
    <AAA>
      <Name>Name_C</Name>
      <Value>Val_C</Value>
      <dateReported>1/1/2012</dateReported>
    </AAA>
    <AAA>
      <Name>Name_D</Name>
      <Value>Val_D</Value>
      <dateReported>1/1/2011</dateReported>
    </AAA>
    <BB>
        <ID>112</ID>
        <dateCreated>1/1/2011</dateCreated>

    </BB>
        <BB>
        <ID>121</ID>
        <dateCreated>1/1/2012</dateCreated>
    </BB>
    <BB>
        <ID>12</ID>
        <dateCreated>1/1/2015</dateCreated>
    </BB>
    <CC>
        <Type>XML</Type>
        <dateUpdated>1/1/2015</dateCreated>
    </CC>
     <CC>
        <Type>TXT</Type>
        <dateUpdated>3/3/2015</dateUpdated>
    </CC>
     <CC>
        <Type>XLS</Type>
        <dateUpdated>2/2/2015</dateUpdated>
    </CC>
</XMLDoc>
```

I have SQL written below

```
SELECT
        ID,
        Name = C1.value('(/XMLDoc/AAA/Name)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
        Value = C1.value('(/XMLDoc/AAA/Value)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
        BB_ID = C1.value('(/XMLDoc/BB/ID)[1]', 'int'), 
        CC_Type = C1.value('(/XMLDoc/CC/Type)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
From T1
```

We need output as

```
Id Name, Value, BB_ID, CC_Type
1  Name_B Val_B  12    TXT
```

Need your inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have search internet and find nice way to handle max:

This is table I used:
`CREATE TABLE #xmlTable (ID INT, xmlData XML)`

Select:

```
SELECT 
    ID
    , xmlData.value ('(/XMLDoc/AAA[not(/XMLDoc/AAA/dateReported > dateReported)]/Name)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS Name
    , xmlData.value ('(/XMLDoc/AAA[not(/XMLDoc/AAA/dateReported > dateReported)]/Value)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS Value
    , xmlData.value ('(/XMLDoc/BB[not(/XMLDoc/BB/dateCreated > dateCreated)]/ID)[1]', 'INT') AS BB_ID
    , xmlData.value ('(/XMLDoc/CC[not(/XMLDoc/CC/dateUpdated > dateUpdated)]/Type)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS CC_Type
FROM #xmlTable AS xt
```

And finally result:

```
ID  Name    Value   BB_ID   CC_Type  
1   Name_B  Val_B   121     TXT
```

The solution I found in this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/3786761/1692632

Answer (score 1):

Your XML sample is horribly wrong - lots of closing tags aren't really closing tag, several don't match the opening tags, and there's a `</x>` in the middle of it all without any opening tag whatsoever...... next time, please try to make sure what you post is **actually valid XML!**

Try with this code:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, XmlContent XML)

INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES(1, '<XMLDoc>
    <AAA>
      <Name>Name_A</Name>
      <Value>Val_A</Value>
      <dateReported>1/1/2001</dateReported>
    </AAA>
    <AAA>
      <Name>Name_B</Name>
      <Value>Val_B</Value>
      <dateReported>1/1/2014</dateReported>
    </AAA>
    <AAA>
      <Name>Name_C</Name>
      <Value>Val_C</Value>
      <dateReported>1/1/2012</dateReported>
    </AAA>
    <AAA>
      <Name>Name_D</Name>
      <Value>Val_D</Value>
      <dateReported>1/1/2011</dateReported>
    </AAA>
    <BB>
        <ID>112</ID>
        <dateCreated>1/1/2011</dateCreated>
    </BB>
    <BB>
        <ID>121</ID>
        <dateCreated>1/1/2012</dateCreated>
    </BB>
    <BB>
        <ID>12</ID>
        <dateCreated>1/1/2015</dateCreated>
    </BB>
    <CC>
        <Type>XML</Type>
        <dateUpdated>1/1/2015</dateUpdated>
    </CC>
     <CC>
        <Type>TXT</Type>
        <dateUpdated>3/3/2015</dateUpdated>
    </CC>
     <CC>
        <Type>XLS</Type>
        <dateUpdated>2/2/2015</dateUpdated>
    </CC>
</XMLDoc>')

;WITH XmlData AS
(
    SELECT 
        ID,
        NodeType = 'AAA',
        RelevantDate = XC.value('(dateReported)[1]', 'datetime'),
        Name = XC.value('(Name)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        Value = XC.value('(Value)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
    FROM 
        @T1
    CROSS APPLY
        XmlContent.nodes('/XMLDoc/AAA') XT(XC)

    UNION

    SELECT 
        ID,
        NodeType = 'BB',
        RelevantDate = XC.value('(dateCreated)[1]', 'datetime'),
        Name = null,
        Value = XC.value('(ID)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
    FROM 
        @T1
    CROSS APPLY
        XmlContent.nodes('/XMLDoc/BB') XT(XC)

    UNION

    SELECT 
        ID,
        NodeType = 'CC',
        RelevantDate = XC.value('(dateUpdated)[1]', 'datetime'),
        Name = XC.value('(Type)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        Value = null
    FROM 
        @T1
    CROSS APPLY
        XmlContent.nodes('/XMLDoc/CC') XT(XC)
)
SELECT 
    xd.ID,
    Name = MAX(Name),
    Value = MAX(Value),
    BB_ID = MAX(BB_ID),
    CC_Type = MAX(CC_Type)
FROM 
    XmlData xd
WHERE
    xd.RelevantDate = (SELECT MAX(xd1.RelevantDate) FROM XmlData xd1 WHERE xd1.NodeType = xd.NodeType)
GROUP BY
    xd.ID
```

This gives me output of:

[image]

Basically, taking your XML, I'm creating a CTE (Common Table Expression) that extracts the relevant info for each of the "node types" - the `<AAA>` nodes, the `<BB>` and the `<CC>` nodes. Then, I can get the `MAX()` for the date for each of those groups by selecting from that CTE.

Comment: apologies next time shall take care  of it. Your output  doesn't match .. I need data nodes for the max date value whereas query gives only max date value

Comment: Thanks but this query gives 3 rows, I want the output as single row Id Name, Value, BB_ID, CC_Type
1  Name_B Val_B  12    TXT

Comment: @Saravanan: updated my response *yet again* - does *this* now match your needs?