# Using SimpleXML to read the last tag ID

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I need to append new tags to a XML file and I can achieve this by using this code:

```
$file = 'xml/config.xml';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

$galleries = $xml->examples;

$gallery = $galleries->addChild('Example');
$gallery->addChild('ExampleID', '123');
$gallery->addChild('ExampleText', 'this is text');
$gallery->addChild('ExampleDate', '23/12/1234');

$xml->asXML($file);
```

My problem is the ID.
Basically I need to get the last ExampleID and increment it to the new Example tag.

How can I achieve this?

> Edit

This is the XML structure:

```
<Examples>
    <Example>
    <ExampleID>1</ExampleID>
    <ExampleText>this is text</ExampleText>
    ...
    </Example>
    <Example>
    <ExampleID>2</ExampleID>
    <ExampleText>this is the secont text</ExampleText>
    ...
    </Example>
</Examples>
```

Comment: Can you post your `xml` file code?

Comment: I thought that was easy to figured it out with the code. I'll post an Example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XPath `last()` to find the last `<Example>` element, and then return the corresponding `<ExampleID>` child :

```
//Example[last()]/ExampleID
```

Alternatively, you can find the maximum `ExampleID`, as mentioned in the other answer :

```
//ExampleID[not(. < //ExampleID)]
```

---

**Demo :** ([eval.in](https://eval.in/572107))

```
$raw = <<<XML
<Examples>
    <Example>
    <ExampleID>1</ExampleID>
    <ExampleText>this is text</ExampleText>
    ...
    </Example>
    <Example>
    <ExampleID>2</ExampleID>
    <ExampleText>this is the secont text</ExampleText>
    ...
    </Example>
</Examples>
XML;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($raw);
$lastID = (string)$xml->xpath("//Example[last()]/ExampleID")[0];
echo $lastID;
```

**Output :**

```
2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XPATH`. Here is the solution.

```
(string)$xml->xpath("//Examples/Example[not(../Example/ExampleID > ExampleID)]")[0]->ExampleID
```

Solution taken from http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php & https://stackoverflow.com/a/3786761

Comment: Can you explain the [0]? And also, I need to get the last example's ID, not the first.

Comment: You want the maximum example's ID right? Does it serve your purpose? `[0]` is for first 0 index

Comment: The Examples lenght is exactly what I need to get the last Example. How can I get it?

Comment: The Xpath expression return a node list of  all `Example` elements with an `ExampeId` where its sibling nodes (and itself) does not contain a larger `ExampleId` value. In other words it returns the `Example` nodes with the largest value in the ExampleId child node. Because it is a node list the result is an array. It could be empty if here is no node. The `[0]` accesses the first element in the returned array.