# XPath to find element with the highest value

Tags: xml, xpath

I would like to create a XPath expression that would return the title of the highest grossing movie, but I'm unable to do so.

I already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786443/xpath-to-get-the-element-with-the-highest-id) and other similiar questions and while they were helpful I couldn't make any of those solutions work for my case. I tried to modify the XPath, but it returns all titles and I don't really what to do to fix it.

Here is my .xml file and below is my XPath expression

```
<movie_database>
  <movies>

    <movie>
      <title>Movie 1</title>
      <finance_records>
        <gross>56,000,000 $</gross>
      </finance_records>      
    </movie>
    
    <movie>
      <title>Movie 2</title>
      <finance_records>
        <gross>150,100,055 $</gross>
      </finance_records>       
    </movie>
    
    <movie>
      <title>Movie 3</title>
      <finance_records>
        <gross>100,577,000 $</gross>
      </finance_records>       
    </movie>
  </movies>
</movie_database>
```

`./movie_database/movies/movie[finance_records[not(../finance_records/gross/number(translate(.," ,$","")) > gross/number(translate(.," ,$","")))]]/title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For xpath 1.0 try:

```
//movie[not(..//movie//gross/number(translate(.," ,$","")) > .//gross/number(translate(.," ,$","")))]/title
```

With xpath > 1.0 try:

```
//movie[.//gross/number(translate(.," ,$","")) = max(..//movie//gross/number(translate(.," ,$","")))]/title
```

In either case, `Movie 2` should be returned.

Comment: @ObéznyPäťdesiatnik Glad it worked for you!

Comment: Your XPath 1.0 expression would actually require XPath 2.0 due to its use of a function call in the final step of the expression.  Also, this question has been asked many times in the past -- easy to find a duplicate for it.